# Pie menu goes away after selecting an option

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, pie-menu

For example when I used the pie menu to set the mode to edit mode, the pie menu immediately goes away after i select edit mode. How do I keep the pie menu floating even after multiple lmb clicks on the menu. There was a similar post here which was old, and I'm asking this again because the pie menus are updated now maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

Pie menus are not intended to stay there and if it would be possible it would be a terrible workflow to get used to. I'd reaaly like to see popups like Shift + A stay but pie menus don't even have the right layout and would take up way too much space.